# Lumen is not migrating package tables when executing phpunit

Tags: laravel, migration, lumen

In my Lumen app, when I execute

```
php artisan migrate --seed
```

it works well.

But when I try to run my tests with `phpunit`, it doesn't run migration from a Laravel package that I coded, so all tests fail

I run my migrations in my test with :

```
Artisan::call('migrate');
```

I use in memory testing for faster running.

Here is my Lumen app Testcase.php

```
abstract class TestCase extends Laravel\Lumen\Testing\TestCase
{
    /** @var array */
    protected $dispatchedNotifications = [];
    protected static $applicationRefreshed = false;
    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     * @return \Laravel\Lumen\Application
     */
    /**
     * Creates the application.
     *
     */
    public function createApplication()
    {
        return self::initialize();
    }

    private static $configurationApp = null;

    public static function initialize()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';
        if (is_null(self::$configurationApp)) {
            $app->environment('testing');

            if (config('database.default') == 'sqlite') {

                $db = app()->make('db');
                $db->connection()->getPdo()->exec("pragma foreign_keys=1");
            }

            Artisan::call('migrate');
            Artisan::call('db:seed');

            self::$configurationApp = $app;
        }

        return $app;
    }


    /**
     * Refresh the application instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function forceRefreshApplication()
    {
        if (!is_null($this->app)) {
            $this->app->flush();
        }
        $this->app = null;
        self::$configurationApp = null;
        self::$applicationRefreshed = true;
        parent::refreshApplication();
    }
    ...
```

In my package, I use in the boot method of service provider:

```
$this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../database/migrations');
```

and then a test example:

```
class TournamentsTest extends TestCase
{

    use DatabaseTransactions, AttachJwtToken;
    protected $initialTournamentNum = 6;
    protected $defaultPagintation = 25;
    protected $user;


    /** @test */
    public function user_can_see_tournament_list()
    {
        $response = $this
            ->call('GET', '/tournaments');
        $this->assertEquals(HttpResponse::HTTP_OK, $response->status());
    }
    ...
```

All my test fail with:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: ken_venue
```

ken_venue is a table that come from the laravel package

In fact, I have this same package working well in a Laravel 5.7 application. but I am migrating this app to a Lumen app.

Any idea why is it happening ?

Comment: Did you publish the migration files from the package into your migrations folder?

Comment: Nop. I don't think this is necesary at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few remarks first:

Your test function does not start with `test`, for me in Laravel such tests would not execute.

Second try this to run the seeds instead of calling migrate and seed by hand

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ShippingCostTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations; // call migrations this way

    public function testDoesApply() // start your function with the word 'test'

        $this->assertTrue(true); // call assert functions
    }

    protected function setUp() // use this function for setup
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->seed(); // call this for seeding
    }
}
```

Third: do you use the same databast type (e.g. MySQL in both cases), because of you use sqlite for testing the syntax might break all of the sudden because of differences between systems.

Comment: it doesn't start with test_ but it has /** @test */ so it will triggers